# Merging 3 .CSV documents into one

Tags: powershell

This is `lab8.ps1` everything is working just fine it takes the .csv splits it by the delimiter, and grabs the first field which is the first name then it goes and grabs the last name of the user and puts it into a .txt document for later use.

```
for ($n = 1; $n -lt 100; $n++) {
$test = (Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\Lab8_db1.csv")[$n].Split(",")
    for ($i = 0;  $i -lt 1; $i++) {
        (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($test[$i]) >> "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\UsersF.txt"
        for ($i = 1;  $i -lt 2; $i++) {
            (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($test[$i]) >> "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\UsersL.txt"
        }
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 99; $i++) {
    $concatFirstWEmail = (Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\UsersF.txt")[$i]
    $emails = "$concatFirstWEmail".ToLower() + "Senecacolleg.biz" >> "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\emails.txt"
}

Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\UsersF.txt" -Header GivenName -Delimiter "," |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv"
Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\UsersL.txt" -Header SurName -Delimiter "," |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersL.csv"
Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\emails.txt" -Header emails -Delimiter "," |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\emails.csv"
```

`mergelab8.ps1` contains

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersL.csv"
$CSV3 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\emails.csv"
$CSV1.GivenName + $CSV2.SurName + $CSV3.emails >> "$HOME\Documents\lab8\test.csv"
```

How can I merge all three of these files into one .csv so that I get this output?

```
Ylnum Vybghjv ylnumSenecacolleg.biz
Dexcd Mnyuait dexcdSenecacolleg.biz
Igbos Nlbihjz igbosSenecacolleg.biz
Rzjlr Wddbcjp rzjlrSenecacolleg.biz
Jjjwa Qylrkoe jjjwaSenecacolleg.biz
```

Comment: Sounds like homework..

Comment: These where the instructions 4. Use the concatenation operator “+” to join CSV1-3 and place commas between CSV1 and CSV2 and between CSV2 and CSV3.

Comment: I'm so close to the answer, when I do this it doesn't join the field with the "," delimiter why? $CSV4 = $CSV1.GivenName[0] + $CSV2.SurName[0] + $CSV3.emails[0]-join ',' | Set-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\test.txt"